# Integer date from SPSS to Python date

Tags: python, pandas, date, spss

I have dates imported from SPSS to Python via pandas. The dates are imported as integers (ordinal). For instance the date `"2015-08-02"` is imported as `13657852800`. When I try

```
pd.to_datetime(13657852800, unit="s")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-ae44044ad39e>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(13657852800, unit="s")

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 611, in to_datetime
    result = convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 203, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    errors=errors)

  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 356, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime

OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'
```

I also tried the following after I learn spss origin date is `"1582-10-14"`

```
pd.to_datetime(13657852800, unit="us", origin="1582-10-14")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-a90cfe340ca5>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(13657852800, unit="us", origin="1582-10-14")

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 571, in to_datetime
    arg = _adjust_to_origin(arg, origin, unit)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 379, in _adjust_to_origin
    "origin {origin} is Out of Bounds".format(origin=origin))

OutOfBoundsDatetime: origin 1582-10-14 is Out of Bounds
```

How to convert spss ordinal integer date into an actual date in python using panda's `to_datetime` function?

Answer (score 3):

After some time, I came up with a solution to this. To make the origins of SPSS and Python match each other is necessary to rescale the integer from SPSS with the number `12219379200` i.e. the number of seconds existing between `"1582-10-14"` and `"1970-01-01"` (the origin used by `to_datetime`)

```
pd.to_datetime(13657852800-12219379200, unit="s")
```

Returns

```
Timestamp('2015-08-02 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that pandas have the min and max boundary for datetime object

```
pd.Timestamp.min
Out[349]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')
pd.Timestamp.max
Out[350]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

But in SPSS I think the min will be on year ***1582***, and possible way for this problem

```
pd.to_datetime((13657852800/86400)-141428, unit='D')
Out[348]: Timestamp('2015-08-02 00:00:00')
```