# Convert datetime column in seconds (?) to pandas date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
s = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(",Unnamed: 0,date\n0,0,13837781820.0\n1,1,13837781880.0\n")
)["date"]
```

I don't know what the date *should* be other than

- it certainly isn't 1970.
- it certainly isn't in the future
- it certainly is within the last year.

```py
pd.to_datetime(s)
```

returns

```
0   1970-01-01 00:00:13.837781820
1   1970-01-01 00:00:13.837781880
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

which is wrong.

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(s[0])
```

returns

```
datetime.datetime(2408, 7, 2, 13, 17)
```

which is wrong.

## Edit

Adding something which is a bit more concrete -

I would expect:

```
13838574120.0
```

to convert to

```
2021-04-23 16:22:00
```

Comment: Is `pd.to_datetime(s.astype(np.int64)/10, unit="s")` meaningful in terms of date?

Comment: Shot in the dark: Could it be a [Lilian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilian_date) expressed in seconds? The numbers seem to be in the right ballpark...

Comment: "invented by Bruce G. Ohms of IBM in 1986" @TurePålsson , this is promising as the files are spss files (IBM) (or maybe coincidence ha)

Comment: @TurePålsson any idea how this would be implemented? I've updated with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my guess is correct, then what you have is seconds from 14. October 1582. A common way of representing dates in the Unix world is seconds from 1. January 1970, so if we can find the difference between those dates in seconds, we can subtract that number from what you have, and take it from there.

To find the difference, we could sit down with pencil and paper and think really hard about leap year rules, or we could let the computer do the work for us:

```
import datetime

# This really should be zero, but just for good measure...
unix_epoch = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
assert unix_epoch.timestamp() == 0

lilian_epoch = datetime.datetime(1582, 10, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
delta = unix_epoch.timestamp() - lilian_epoch.timestamp()
```

Now let's try it with your sample date

```
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(13838574120.0 - delta))
# prints 2021-04-23 18:22:00
```

Why is it two hours off? I'm in Stockholm, and `fromtimestamp` gives local time, but timestamp values are supposed to be UTC. You'll have to adjust for timezone, somehow.

Comment: Interesting thanks! A few hours ago I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487446 so you're right about the "lilian" time stamp :) and the delta that you have is that value, thank you for the additional information. I'm curious how you're aware of lilian dates? Seems quite obscure

Comment: I had never heard of them before this. :-) The numbers looked about right for being seconds from some point in the past. With your information that the dates you had were all in this year, I checked where the starting point would be, and found fifteen-eighty-something. This was suspiciously close to the start of the Gregorian calendar, so I looked for time representations using that as a starting point, and got lucky with the first one I found.

Comment: ah ok - nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue in number of digits because `10 digit epoch time` is required if you want your datetime in `seconds` and `13 digit epoch time` is required for the resulting time to be in `miliseconds`. I just removed the last digit and it worked.

```
pd.to_datetime(s//10, unit = "s")
```

[image]

Comment: nice - unfortunately this is wrong though (date is certainly within the last year - the expected year is 2021)

Comment: Then the issue maybe in epoch time itself :)

Comment: I don't think so - i can open this datetime in R Haven, tho i've no idea how it's working, so i'm fairly confident that the float has meaning, it's just i don't know how to parse with python, i've updated the example